Why 3 downvotes on this question?
I asked Program/library to generate many technical indicators given a series of stock prices. It received 3 downvotes,  without any explanation. I am new to this website: what's with this question?

Question body:

I have a time series (vector) representing the evolution of a stock price over time. I am looking for a program/library that can generate a matrix containing as many technical indicators as possible. Which publicly available program/library can do that?


My bet is that it is because this question is closely related to seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy which is considered as off-topic as per the site's guidelines.

Thanks. I don't understand why people mix up downvotes with close votes.

This often happens indeed.

Also, where did you see that seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy is considered as off-topic?

I've tried to find a link as well but did not manage to do so. However, if you take some random question on the site and click close, a menu will pop up with the different possible reasons, amongst which 'off-topic' and then several propositions along with this one.

I see. This close reason sounds extremely vague.

It is. This is why some questions about developing a trading strategy sometimes stay open. I guess it all depends on the interpretation the community gives to the 'unlikely to help others' part.

That doesn't sound good. Before our comments get wiped out: When should we close a question as seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy?
